# How to create titles that reveal more text when clicked using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i would like to create an HTML documents containing a few h2 titles and some text under each h2 but i would like for the differents text parts to remain hidden until i click on the corresponding h2 title and goes back to hidden state if i click a second time on the title. How do i create clickable titles that reveal text or hide text when clicked, using CSS? Thanks

Here is an example of what i would like to achieve for the HTML part:

```
 <h1>Main title</h1>

 <p>random text</p>
    
    <h2> First clickable title </h2>

      <p>first text that appears and disappears when i click on first clickable title</p>

    <h2> Second clickable title </h2>

      <p>second text that appears and disappears when i click on second clickable title</p>
    
    <h2> Third clickable title </h2>

      <p>third text that appears and disappears when i click on third clickable title</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: What you are looking for is called an accordion component. Google it, and you will find a ton of examples how to do that. For example: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/create-css-based-content/

Answer (score 0):

You will need javascript to perform that task

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Main title</h1>

    <p class="change_text" style="display: none">random text</p>

    <h2>First clickable title</h2>

    <p>
      first text that appears and disappears when i click on first clickable
      title
    </p>

    <h2 class="second_h2">Second clickable title</h2>

    <p>
      second text that appears and disappears when i click on second clickable
      title
    </p>

    <h2>Third clickable title</h2>

    <p>
      third text that appears and disappears when i click on third clickable
      title
    </p>

    <script>
        const h2 = document.querySelector('.second_h2')
        
        h2.addEventListener('click' , () => {
            document.querySelector(".change_text").style.display = 'block'
        })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here a simple approach for your problem

Here, whenever the second h2 element is clicked, the paragraph will be visible.